# RecyclerView jumps to top when notifyDataSetChanged() called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment that contains `swipeRefreshLayout` and infinity `recyclerView` in it. My fragment layout code is similar to:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        .
        .
        .
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        .
        .
        .
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_main_news"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I set recyclerView's adapter in `onViewCreated()` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onResume()`. In some devices like Samsung Galaxy A5 , when user go back to fragment and `notifyDataSetChanged` called, `recyclerView` moves to top and show first item.

How can I prevent this?
Thanks in advance.

**Update:** This is my `onResume()` code that calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
override fun onResume() {
super.onResume()
    if (rv.adapter != null)
        (rv.adapter as MyAdapter).apply {
            fontSize = Options.getFontSize()
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you add your [Java/Kotlin] code? (On refresh part)

Comment: Please paste the code where you notify RecyclerView

Comment: @Squti I have update my question.

Answer (score 1):

it's expected that when `notifyDataSetChanged` called entire view is refreshed. When you go back to the fragment onResume is called, subsequently your `notifyDataSetChanged` also called. That's why you see the first item.

So, to prevent this you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` when your whole data is changed or need to be updated.

I can suggest you some way.

remove notifyDataSetChanged from onResume & use `diffUtil` for your recyclerView data update. It will update only your changed item. Update your data only when it's necessary, like if you update any data in details & want to update in list you can override `onActivityResult` & notify your list there. Or you can send broadcast & receive it in you list fragment & notify you list.

thanks in advance, hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my app when we click on items of list, in detail page we can change app settings like font size. So when we go back to list, the list should be updated as needed. And list data is not increasing. So I have no choice but to call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I think solution is to use diffUtil for recyclerView. there are many resources in online if you don't know about it. please apply it & let me know the update

Answer (score -1):

You can try save scrolling state of the RV when updating:

```
 val recyclerViewState = rv.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()            
 rv?.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState)
```

Comment: Thank for reply. I tried it but it didn't work and still recyclerview jumps to top.